# How to create a click to call button without navigating away from the current page?

Tags: javascript, html, dialing

I have a "Click to call" button on my website. Then the user clicks it, he/she is navigated to a different page.

Here is my HTML markup

```
<a href="tel:+18001234567" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block click-to-call">
    <strong>Call Now</strong>
</a>
```

How can I change my code so that the user stays on the same page when they click to call? My goal is to trigger the phone to dial a given number while keeping the user on the same page.

Comment: How do you send the signal, using API ?

Comment: I see the confusion. When the user clicks the link, I want the phone to place the call

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ?https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/

Comment: Is this number correct ? I think your mobile number is wrong US numbers contain 11 digits but this number contains only 10 digits.

Comment: +18001234567 worked for me, checked on IOS https://jsfiddle.net/vqmkfaxj/5/

Answer (score 1):

Click to call function requires two requirements.

> Wrap all phone numbers in hyperlinks with the tel: schema.
>
> Always use the international dialing format.

According to your HTML markup your number format is wrong. US numbers contain 11 digits but yours only contains 10 digits.

```
<a href="tel:+1800123456" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block click-to-call">
    <strong>Call Now</strong>
</a>
```

Please use correct number format.

```
<a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111">+1 (303) 499-7111</a>
```

For more info: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/

I have tested this https://jsfiddle.net/vqmkfaxj/5/ on IOS and worked for me, refer the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ro4T.png).